# How to simulate click button to show modal with jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to trigger the `click` on a remote modal button. After an `alert` dialog closed. The reason is I want to check if a user passed. If not an alert display 'you need to login'. After a user click ok. A login modal show up.

I can only do the alert but I don't know why a click is not trigger. Here's the code...

[login link is in the hamburger]

```js
(function() {
  'use strict'

  document.querySelector('#navbarSideCollapse').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.querySelector('.offcanvas-collapse').classList.toggle('open')
  })

  $('#xModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    var button = $(e.relatedTarget);
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-body').load(button.data("remote"));
  });


})()

function login_first() {
  alert('Please login first!');
  $('#login_btn').click();
}
```

```css
  @media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .offcanvas-collapse {
      position: fixed;
      top: 56px;
      /* Height of navbar */
      bottom: 0;
      right: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      padding-right: 1rem;
      padding-left: 1rem;
      overflow-y: auto;
      visibility: hidden;
      background-color: #343a40;
      transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, visibility .3s ease-in-out;
    }

    .offcanvas-collapse.open {
      visibility: visible;
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
  }
  div.body{
    margin-top:100px !important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="content">
<main>
  <div class="row">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark" aria-label="Main navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Offcanvas navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler p-0 border-0" type="button" id="navbarSideCollapse" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse offcanvas-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
      <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" id="login_btn" href="#xModal" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-remote="login-form.php" data-bs-target="#xModal">LOGIN HERE!</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Notifications</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Switch account</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Settings</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>  
  </div>
  
  <div class="row body">
  <h2>
  Click <button id="proceed" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="login_first();">here</button> to proceed!
  </h2>
  </div>
</main>
</div>




<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="xModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">LOGIN</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">[login form here]</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or here for fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/a8skfyd3/

Comment: Have you considered using a confirm dialog instead? Save it in a variable and if true, then execute the click event.  Just off the top of my head the click might not be triggering because of your alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code worked for me.  I also tried it in your supplied fiddle.  I pulled the click handler out of your html.  Used a confirm dialog instead of an alert - that way a person can decline to login.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function login_first() {
    let shouldLogin = confirm("Please log in first!")
    if (shouldLogin) {
      document.querySelector('#login_btn').click();
    }
  }

  document.querySelector('#proceed').addEventListener('click', login_first)
})
```